# What permission must the user have on source and target on-prem servers for DMA assessment and migrate to work correctly?

Tags: sql-server, migration, sql-server-data-migration-assistant

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15

It doesn't say anything on what exact permissions need to be given to the user on the source and target **on-prem** sql server for the **assessment** and **migration** to work correctly?

Note: For assessment only, target server need not be installed.

Any reference will be helpful so that I can plan user permission in advance.

Answer (score 2):

From the same document, it is mentioned as below:

[image: Prerequidsite]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/dma/dma-overview?view=sql-server-ver15#prerequisites

Not sure, if you needed something else.

Comment: Ok thanks this is for assessment. What about the actual migration?

Comment: Please explain about actual issue and post another question so that one can answer that.

Comment: In my question I have asked what is permission required for source and target user for assessment and migration. You have answered about assessment, can you also answer about migration please?

Comment: The required permission would be sysadmin and read-write role on the folder where the files will reside.